# Showing many-to-many in an Restful API using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, api, sqlite, rest, model-view-controller

I've setup a DBInitializer to add some test data in my ASP.net MVC project, and set up an API to show the data. Everything comes up, but I've added a many-to-many relationship between two tables and the data doesn't show up[image]

The initializer:
{

```
            HouseModel[] houses =
            {
                new HouseModel {ID = 1, Name = "house1"},
                new HouseModel {ID = 2, Name = "house2"},
                new HouseModel {ID = 3, Name = "house3"}
            };

            PersonModel[] people =
            {
                new PersonModel {ID = 1, Name = "person1", Nickname = "pers1" },
                new PersonModel {ID = 2, Name = "person2", Nickname = "pers2" },
                new PersonModel {ID = 3, Name = "person3", Nickname = "pers3" }
            };
            db.HouseModels.AddRange(houses);
            db.PersonModels.AddRange(people);
            db.SaveChanges();

            for (int i = 0; i < houses.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Console");
                houses[i].PersonModels.Add(people[i]);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I've tried googling about everything, wasted hours trying to figure this out, someone tell me why I'm an idiot and leave an explanation and it would make my day! <3

EDIT, code for HouseModel + PersonModel

{

```
public class HouseModel
{
    public HouseModel() {}
    
    // Auto incremented ID
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    // Name of house
    [Required]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // List of Rooms connected to house
    public ICollection<RoomModel> RoomModels { get; set; } = new List<RoomModel>();

    // List of Users connected to house
    public ICollection<PersonModel> PersonModels { get; set; } = new List<PersonModel>();
}
```

{

public class PersonModel
{
public PersonModel() {}

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    public ICollection<HouseModel> HouseModels { get; set; } = new List<HouseModel>();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don' t post the pictures, post the real code if you want to get some help. Pls post the HouseModels and PersonModels classes

Comment: Oh I must've forgot @Serge, updated main post

Answer (score 0):

I would never recommend it but here the most experts  would recommend you use 2 classes like these

```
public class House
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons {get; set;}
}
public class Person
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Nickname {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<House> Houses {get; set;}
}
```

after db migrating  you can use code like

```
            var people =
            {
                new Person { Name = "person1", Nickname = "pers1",
                 Houses= new List<House> { new House {Name = "house1"}}
                },
                new Person { Name = "person2", Nickname = "pers2" ,
                  Houses= new List<House> { new House {Name = "house2"}}
                },
                new PersonModel { Name = "person3", Nickname = "pers3" 
                  Houses= new List<House> { new House {Name = "house3"}}
                }
            };
           db.Set<Person>().AddRange(people);
           db.SaveChanges();
```